# BarcodeRecognize can read Chinese,but why BarcodeImage can't make Chinese characters to QR image?

Tags: image-processing

For example:

```
Import["http://www.image-share.com/upload/2735/230.jpg"]
BarcodeRecognize@%
```

can give a String "别看我，我会害羞..."
but if I go on using `BarcodeImage` on the output:

```
BarcodeImage@%
```

It will throw a *warning*:

> BarcodeImage called with 1 argument; 2 or 3 arguments are expected.

So how could I use `BarcodeImage` to make Chinese characters to QR image?

Comment: The bug has been repaired in 10.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem seems to be a mixture of three things

1. You didn't put all the necessary arguments for [`BarcodeImage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarcodeImage.html)
2. [`BarcodeImage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarcodeImage.html) is limited on text encoding (against standards)
3. The documentation is poor and does not describe the existing limitation

### The good

```
img = Import["http://www.image-share.com/upload/2735/230.jpg"];
str = BarcodeRecognize@img
```

> "别看我，我会害羞..."

Or as an image for poorly configured devices

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

So far so good

### The bad

Now [`BarcodeImage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarcodeImage.html) needs to be called with two arguments, *as the error you got explained*.

Then do:

```
BarcodeImage["text", "QR"]
```

But not

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The second arguments can be any of these:

**1D:** "UPC", "EAN8", "EAN13", "Code39", "Code128", "ITF", "Codabar"

**2D:** "Aztec", "DataMatrix", "QR", "PDF417"

### The ugly

We get an error even for proper use, and the clue is in the error message

```
BarcodeImage[str, "QR"]
```

> *BarcodeImage::qr: Expecting a string of characters defined in ISO/IEC 8859-1 of length up to 2953, a string of alphanumeric characters of length 4296, or a string of digits of length up to 7089 instead of 别看我，我会害羞.... >>*

I guess Chinese characters are not encoded in **ISO/IEC 8859-1**.

Shamefully the documentation says nothing about encoding limitations.
This is very unfortunate implementation from Mathematica, QR codes are supposed to [accept various encodings](http://www.qrcode.com/en/faq.html) .

### Workaround

Wolfram alpha doesn't seem to have that limitation

```
WolframAlpha["QR code \"别看我，我会害羞...\""]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

So you can get a clean output by

```
chineseQR[str_String] :=  WolframAlpha["QR code \"" <> str <> "\"", {{"QRCodeBarcode", 1}, "Content"}]
```

And for future use:

```
chineseQR[str]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: oh,Just had the same idea with you when I reopen the browser.I think this is a good idea.just as an old saying goes:心有灵犀一点通.

Comment: @user15961, Probably you could write to Wolfram Technical Support requesting  full implementation in future releases. In Mathematica > Help > Give Feedback...

Comment: Yeah,I will feedback this problem to them.

Answer (score 3):

yes, we can do this way:

```
 barcodeImage[x_String] :=ImageCrop@Image@Rasterize@WolframAlpha["QR code:" <> x,{{"QRCodeBarcode", 1}, "Content"}];
```

and then

```
barcodeImage@"中文"
BarcodeRecognize@%(*Chinese*)
```

will return the result!